# GCP Dataflow - getting skipping pod synchronization error log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

After submitting gcp dataflow job, i can see some error logs getting
triggered of severity=ERROR and resource.type="dataflow_step"

Not sure what exactly causing this issue

```
skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet, PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful]
message: "skipping pod synchronization - container runtime status check may not have completed yet"
```

Has any one came across such issue.

Comment: In my organization we run tens of production Dataflow jobs every day and I've come across these same messages in the logs as well. I also do not know what causes it, however as an anecdotal point it has not given us any issues (our jobs run successfully as far as I can tell). Perhaps its expected? Are your jobs failing? If so there is probably another underlying issue to investigate.

Comment: @Tanjin even my jobs are running successfully. getting data as expected. But just wanted to know the root cause, and also wether this is something from our side or its something with gcp infra side only.

Comment: This is potentially benign but hard to say without looking at jobs. So if you this these errors are causing issues in your pipeline, please contact Google Cloud Support.

Comment: The [pod syncronization message](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/enabling-dualstack-in-kubernetes/10451) seems somehow related to kubernetes. Be noted that Dataflow is a Google-managed service, it is possible that the error is happening in the underlying services and might be expected; however, as chamikara has mentioned, if you face any inconvinience with this error, please contact [Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support).